# Help needed with Facebook Like Button and AJAX loaded pages

Tags: ajax, wordpress, facebook-like

OK I'm loading each pages and posts (Wordpress) via ajax and it works great. I integrated the iframe Facebook Like Button in the page/post templates and it loads correctly when I load a page or a post.

My only problem it that when I load a page or post and I click on the Like button it is the Open Graph Tags of the main page (header.php via index.php) that are shown on Facebook and not the tags of the page or post I just loaded.

http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise

How can I adjust this? This is the php code for the post template that is being called via ajax:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Ajax Post Using Slug
*/
?>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta property="og:title" content="Portfolio | par Gab Labelle, artisan numérique montréalais" />
<meta property="og:type" content="blog" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/#portfolio" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/visualise.ca-logo2.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="visualise.ca" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="10150720967625327" />
<meta name="description" content="&#171; J'aime croire que ma force réside en ma capacité à trouver l'histoire simple qu'inspirent marques, produits et services et à la présenter de manière intelligible, créative et engageante. &#187;" />
</head>
<body>
...
<?php the_content(); ?>
...
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#appId=153423521399187&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/#portfolio" send="true" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>           
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks for you time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the page URL you want to "Like" in your IFRAME code.

...

"In order for Facebook to grab your meta tags, it needs a unique URL for your content. You're going to have to make a "non-AJAX" version of your landing pages with different URLs, and send that to Facebook as part of the Like button URL. It looks like clicking an item hits /visualise/ajax/ with a "slug" param for the content. You'll want to probably do something like /visualise/viewslug?slug=[blah] and send that to Facebook. It would have the right meta tags and auto-open your AJAX window upon that URL loading."

Comment: This works perfectly, no problem at that level... It is the tags that are not correct: I mean, on Facebook it shows the tags of the main page not the ajax loaded page. i.e og:title, description, etc.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It should be pulling the meta tags of the URL you're trying to Like. Are you sure your URL is being sent to the Like button, and that the URL has the proper meta tags?

Comment: Like I explained... It is a Wordpress page with its own tags loading a post or a page (And with it's own Like Button) within using AJAX. When I click on the Like button of the ajax loaded page or post it gives the right URL on facebook but it doesn't use the right tags. It should be using the post's tags and not the main page's tags.

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining correctly: you will need to generate unique URLs for all of your AJAX-loaded content, and those URLs need to spit out the appropriate meta tags. It looks like your Like button is just pointed at http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/#portfolio which means Facebook is going to grab those meta tags instead.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm not sure if I understand correctly, what you are saying is that http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/#portfolio is actually the same page as http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/ and that is why Facebook uses its tags? If this is correct how can I generate unique URLs for all of your AJAX-loaded content? Many thanks for your time and help by the way.

Comment: In order for Facebook to grab your meta tags, it needs a unique URL for your content. You're going to have to make a "non-AJAX" version of your landing pages with different URLs, and send that to Facebook as part of the Like button URL. It looks like clicking an item hits /visualise/ajax/ with a "slug" param for the content. You'll want to probably do something like /visualise/viewslug?slug=[blah] and send that to Facebook. It would have the right meta tags and auto-open your AJAX window upon that URL loading.